# batch_size as a dimension for weights

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

When reading tutorials on TensorFlow I've come across a few examples where weights are defined to be of a size [batch_size, ...]

**Examples:**

- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent - albeit a bit outdated

```
hidden_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, lstm.state_size])
current_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, lstm.state_size])
```

- https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-ii.html

```
initializer=(tf.zeros([batch_size, state_size]), init_state))
```

From what I know when using mini-batches you feed the network with all examples in your mini-batch. All of these examples will be transformed using the same weights. The weights are updated after the last example is processed based on (for example) average of the individual gradients.

My assumption is that the extended tensor (enlarged by batch_size dimension) is used to quicken the computation by reducing the amount of operations.

Q: **Does it just create `batch_size` copies of weights, which are at the end averaged to result in a state for next mini-batch?** (This would also make variable batch-size straightforward.)

If so, how does one initialize weights to random non-zero values with mean `mu` and standard deviation of `sd`? Do I manually create [input_size, hidden_size] with random values and then create tensor by copying it `batch_size` times resulting in [batch_size, input_size, hidden_size] shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at are the initial cell states for `Recurrent Cells`. Note that, recurrent cells have an internal cell state, which is updated on each call and are then taken out as output after the last call. You can think of it as being output of some layer in vanilla neural network, but you need to have some value in-place for that layer to update.

So, when you are calling a recurrent cell for the first time you'll need to seed these cell states, which means that you need to provide some placeholder values. Now, as you can see, this state is unique for each input and hence you need to seed these cells for each input. Here, in your example, you are seeding the cell state and output with zeros.

As you can see in the image below, we need to provide a cell state and an output state, which is updated on call, and that is why you need to seed two values. 
[image]

The weights you are talking about are actually shared. In the above image, they correspond to multiple gates (i, f, o) and are also used for input x, just like in a neural layer. You can read more about lstms in [this amazing post](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/).

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I had weights and states confused. Now that you pointed that out I see it.